# Which memory slots to use?

Tags: memory, motherboard

I have 2 servers PowerEdge R720xd used as Hyper-V servers, let's call them HV1 and HV2.

HV1 has 32GB of memory, 4x8GB and HV2 has 48GB of memory 12x4GB.

Each server has 2x12 slots of memory, 12 per CPU.

On HV1, used slots are 2-4 and 14-16

On HV2, used slots are 1-2-3-4-6-8 and 13-14-15-16-18-20

I will add soon 4x8GB of memory on each server.

First question : Do you think actual slots are the best mapping ?

Second question : which are the best slots where to add my 4 new 8GB ?

Comment: generally speaking, the only parts of a motherboard manual that I ALWAYS read, are the pinouts for the case lights/buttons, and the memory configuration chart. Channel pairing is important, as is banks-to-CPUs. My Dual Proc server board has one bank of ram only usable for one CPU, and another bank dedicated to the second socket. I hate to say RTFM, but it will give you better more reliable answers than we can, other than by RTFMing ourselves.

Comment: Agreed with Frank. But before you dive into [documentation from hell](http://topics-cdn.dell.com/pdf/poweredge-r720_owner's%20manual_en-us.pdf), try checking out the [R720 Memory Guidelines](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/SLN153646)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Dell Memory Module Installation Guidelines /
Population Rules for the R720xd server

Link courtesy of DrZoo

http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/SLN153646#issue3

[image]